# My Crypter Won't Work?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cryptography, 32bit-64bit, exe

I recently built a Crypter in VB.NET 2010 Express Edition, and I opened up the .exe GUI, and chose a Executable File to Encrypt, and it Crypted. I opened the Crypted File and I recieved an error saying this:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program."

Is there any possible way I can convert my code into 64-Bit? If you need to see my code, just say so in the comments below. Thanks guys, all help is appreciated! :)

Comment: So, wait, you encrypted a file, then tried to execute that encrypted file? What result did you expect when you ran it?

Comment: I know, but isnt supposed to show the encryption?

Comment: What do you mean by "show the encryption"?  You've encrypted a file, and now all you can do with it is view the encrypted contents (with a hex editor, or text editor in a pinch), or decrypt it.

Comment: Ohhhh I have to use a Text Editor... But why the 32-64 Bit error?

Comment: That's just Windows' way of telling you that it doesn't know how to run that .exe.

Comment: I also have one more question, if I wanted to Crypt a Server for a RAT with my Crypter, how could I make it so they can still open the server, even if it is Crypted?

Comment: What is the use case? This is starting to sound like malware.

Comment: Am I not allowed to use a RAT? I am trying to make a Security Website that sells pentesting tools.

Comment: 64bit windows can't run 16bit apps anymore. if your crypter is building a 16bit executable, then it's utterly useless on x64

Comment: Marc, how could I make it run on Windows 64bit?

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is to rename the type of the encrypted file to something else when you've encrypted it. For instance, '*whatever.exe*' could be renamed to '*whatever.exe.encryptedfile*'. If you then associate the filetype '*encryptedfile*' with your application, it will start automatically whenever someone tries to open a file of that type.